# Series of equation giving final answer as zero

Tags: c, codeblocks

I created this program that is intended to use the equation
[F=(CP x CR x D)/(4 x pi x e x ((D^2+R^2)^3/2)]

Where

CR = Charge on Ring

CP = Charge on point

R = radius of Ring

D = Distance between the point and ring

e = 8.85 x 10^-12

F = Force

When I substitue the values

2.00 x 10^-5 for CR (0.00002)

2.00 x 10^-05 for CP (0.00002)

0.90 for R

and 0.30 for D

The final answer should be  F= 1.263759

but instead I get zero. I'm fairly new to programming so any help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double calculatef(double, double, double, double, double, double);
double main()
{
    double CR; //Charge on Ring
    double CP; //Charge on point
    double R; //radius of Ring
    double D; //Distance between the point and ring
    double F; //Force

    int e = 8.85* pow(10,-12);
    printf("Please enter the values for the variables as follows:\n");
    printf("-Charge on the ring,\n -Charge on the point,\n -Radius of the ring\n");
    printf("-And the Distance between the center of the ring and the point:\n");

    scanf("%lf",&CR);
    printf("The charge on the ring is: %f\n", CR);

    scanf("%lf",&CP);
    printf("The charge on the point is: %f\n", CP);

    scanf("%lf",&R);
    printf("The radius of the ring is: %f\n", R);

    scanf("%lf",&D);
    printf("The distance between the center of the ring and the point is: %f\n", D);

    //The charge on the ring is 2e-005 Coulombs.
    //The charge on the point is 2e-005 Coulombs.
    //The radius of the ring is 0.90 m.
    //The distance between the center of the ring and the point is 0.30 m.
    //The force exerted on the point is 1.26 N.

    F == calculatef(CR,CP,R,D,e,F);

    printf("The force exerted on the point is %.2f\n", F);

    system("Pause");
}

double calculatef(double CR, double CP, double R, double D, double e, double F)
{
    e = 8.85* pow (10,-12);
    F=((D*D) * (R*R));
    F=(((CP * CR * D))/(pow(F,3/2)));
    F=(F/( 4 * 3.14 * e ));

    return(F);
}
```

Comment: `F == calculatef(CR,CP,R,D,e,F);` does not look like something you want,

Comment: maybe change `==` to `=`? (VTCing)

Comment: The best help anyone can give you is have you to learn how to use a debugger, with which you can execute one line of your code at a time, and examine values of all variables at each step. Based on it should be laughably easy for you to figure out what your code is actually doing, and why it's doing something different than what you expect. Learning how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can't agree more except the C++ tag. :D

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'll bet he would step over the erroneous statement a thousand times and never figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Your declaration and definition of the `main` function is wrong. It *must* be declared to return an `int`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you pass the variable `F` to the `calculatef` function? There's no need for that, just define it as a local variable inside the function and return it. No need to pass `e` either, it can be defined and initialized in the `calculatef` function.

Comment: You should check compiler warnings. When I compile your program, I get the warnings **warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]** and **note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [@luther](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46503741/2410359) good answer about the type of `e`:

```
// int e = 8.85* pow(10,-12);
double e = 8.85* pow(10,-12);
// or simplify
double e = 8.85e-12;
```

Code uses integer math where FP math is needed.

```
// pow(F,3/2)
pow(F,3.0/2)
```

These problems imply OP does not have all compiler warnings enabled.  Save time - enable them all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your definition of `e`. First of all, you're assigning a very small floating point number to an `int`, effectively making it zero. Second of all, C has its own form of scientific notation, so you don't have to call `pow()`. Try changing the statement to this:

```
double e = 8.85e-12;
```